# Java: toString method printing the hash code instead of inOrder traversal

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, tostring

I am trying to print the toString of BinarySearchTree(Generic), which contains in its body the following:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
    root.inOrderTraversal(root);
    return  "inOrderTraversal has finished";
    }
```

and this is my inOrder traversal, which is inside the BinaryNode class (Generic), used by the BinarySearchTree:

```
public void inOrderTraversal(BinaryNode<T> node)
    {
        if(node != null)
        {
            if(node.left != null)
            {
                inOrderTraversal(node.left);
            }
            System.out.println(node.nodeValue);
            if(node.right != null)
            {
                inOrderTraversal(node.right);
            }
        }
    }
```

After I constructed the Generic BinarySerachTree using Student as its type and printed the toString, it is showing the output as Student@7a81197d, Student@5ca881b5, Student@24d46ca6.
What could be the problem?

```
        Student s1 = new Student("Jasim", 84812); //Name and his/her ID
        Student s2 = new Student("Yousef", 845623);
        Student s3 = new Student("Zack", 432553);
        Student s4 = new Student("Zara", 54233);
        BinarySearchTree<Student> bst = new BinarySearchTree<Student>(s1); //construction
        bst.insert(s2);
        bst.insert(s3); 
        System.out.println(bst.toString()); //Error when printing this.
```

Comment: You need to override `toString` in `Student`

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do that. The instruction of the assignment that I'm doing only allows me to implement it in the BinarySearchTree class. Is there another way to solve the problem?

Comment: instead of `System.out.println(node.nodeValue);`, you can print the content of of nodeValue (we don't have its code): e.g. `System.out.println(node.nodeValue.getName());`  -- BTW: you should rename the posted `toString()` method, can be confusing having it print out instead of just returning a string representation (as specified in documentation)

Comment: `toString()` is supposed to *return* a `String`, not to perform I/O.

Comment: I found out that I can override the toString in Students. So thanks all for your help

Comment: The instructions were not appropriately clear. However, after I asked the professor specifically about this problem, she said that I can implement toString() in STudent class

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you should implement toString() method in your Student pojo.
Currently it is printing the object reference as per java notation

Comment: As for the assignment that I'm doing, I can only add the toString method in BinarySearchTree class.

Comment: Then how will you print the detail of the student

Comment: I reasked the instructor, she said that I can do that. Thank you for the help 
Sathiya.

Answer (score 0):

If your instructor maintains the original requirements, you can try the following：
`

```
public class StudentModal extends Student{
    public StudentModal( String name, Integer id) {
        super(name, id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "userName:" + this.getName() + "id:" +this.getId();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StudentModal student = new StudentModal("test", 1);
    System.out.println(student);
}
```

`